# What precisely is required for this WPF binding to update?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a treeview to which I've added behaviours that allows me to bind to the currently selected item (a dependency property I've named SelectedCourse).  This appears to work just fine, as I can pause the program and confirm that the value of the selected item is changing:

[image]

Here is the XAML binding:

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"
         Text="{Binding SelectedCourse.Description}">
</TextBox>
```

And as you can see, nothing happens in the UI when SelectedCourse gets updated:

(The red box on the right is the textbox.  The red outline comes from Snoop.)

[image]

BindableCourse inherits from DependencyObject, and Description is a dependency property:

```
public class BindableCourse : DependencyObject
{
    public static DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Description",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(BindableCourse));

    public string Description
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DescriptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Now, if I *look* the textbox element in Snoop, SelectedCourse.Description appears in the textbox as desired.

[image]
[image]

Afterward, I can't get the textbox to change; even by, for example, changing SelectedCourse -- and I've checked and SelectedCourse *does* get changed when I select a new element -- and then closing Snoop, reopening it, and then reinspecting the textbox.

wtf is going on?

Comment: `TextBox.Text` binds two ways by default, so it's possible the selected course's description is being changed.  Try adding `Mode=OneWay` to your binding and see if that has any effect.  Assuming you don't want the user to be able to change the description, you should also set `IsReadOnly="True"` on the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using your own custom binding, I think you can do something like the following:

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"
     Text="{Binding ElementName=TreeViewName, Path=SelectedValue.Description}">
</TextBox>
```

The selected value will change depending on the tree view selection. "TreeViewName" is the name of the your treeview using the x:Name attribute.

Comment: Damn, that worked?  I read another thread on SO saying that Binding to SelectedItem doesn't work with TreeViews, so I didn't even try.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a different style of binding that doesn't involve a ViewModel. It binds to a specific control on your View through the ElementName property. The selected value will be bound to the data item that is currently selected in your TreeView.